# I wonder there is any continuous bijection.

Tags: general-topology

In usual topology R^2, let D be a unit circle and D^ be a unit circle without origin.

Question is, there is any continuous bijection(which inverse also continuous)

defined on int(D) to int(D^). I think it is impossible to establish such function,

but i can't find or explain. is it possible?

Comment: The unit circle is the set $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$. What is the unit circle without origin??

Comment: It is a unit circle without (0,0).

Comment: But $(0,0)$ is not on the unit circle.

Comment: bof's point is you're talking about _discs_ here, not circles....

Comment: oh, sorry for my mistake. I am not good at english. ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathring D$ is simply connected and $\mathring{D}\setminus\{0\}$ isn't, they are not homeomorphic.

You can also argue this way: if $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathring D$, then there is a larger compact subset $K^\ast$ of $\mathring D$ such that $\mathring D\setminus K^\ast$ is connected (take $K^*$ equal to a closed disk centered at the orgin with the appropriate radius). But this property doesn't hold on $\mathring D\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

int (D) is simply connected, int(D^) is not simply connected, hence no such function exists.

Comment: That is not correct, since $\mathring D\setminus\{0\}$ *is* connected.

Comment: Ooops, you are right ! simply connected !